# Stack Alert [Mozilla Firefox Add-on] - Keep tabs on your inbox without needing to have a Stack Exchange site open. 

Tags: app, firefox, extension

> ## Not using Firefox?
>
> Don't worry, Stack Alert is available for other browsers as well. Visit the appropriate page for your browser below:
>
> - [Google Chrome](https://stackapps.com/q/2874)
> - [Opera](https://stackapps.com/q/2948)

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

What better way to keep an eye on your inbox than with a Firefox add-on? Now you can tell at a glance how many items are in your inbox without worrying about having a tab open to a Stack Exchange site.

#### License

[GPL version 3](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html)

#### Download

You can install Stack Alert from the Mozilla add-on page here:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stack-alert/

#### Platform

Any platform that runs Mozilla Firefox 8-10

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

The extension is written in JavaScript.

You can get the code here: https://github.com/nathan-osman/Stack-Alert
*(look in the `firefox/` folder for the Firefox-specific code)*

Comment: this doesn't seem to work with the current version of Firefox. When I attempt to give it access to my account it just comes to a complete stop at the "Authorizing Application" page, and doesn't proceed any further. I tried closing firefox and clearing my cache/history/logging in, but it didn't resolve the problem. I was able to get it working in Chrome though.

Comment: @Wipqozn: I can reproduce your problem. I will look into this as soon as possible and let you know when it is fixed.

Comment: I can also confirm it's error in version 10 of Firefox. Hopefully its nothing major..

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Appreciate it.

Comment: @Wipqozn: I have fixed the bug in v0.23 which should make its way to your machine within the next day or two.

Comment: @George will reinstalling the plugin fix it now? (assuming your last comment means an update was pushed)

Comment: @SimonSheehan: No. It has to be approved by Mozilla first. That may take from a few hours to a day or two.

Comment: This addon wasn't working for me on FF 8.x but I recently upgraded to 10.0.1 and it just started working.

Comment: @slm: That's correct - FF 8.x is not supported by Stack Alert.

Comment: It doesn't work in ff 10.0.2. It always says that "an error has occurred" after I authorize it, and then it doesn't display any new notifications. I'm using linux.

Comment: @Christofian: I will look into it and let you know what the problem is.

Comment: well, it does display a number one when there is a new notification, but when I click the button it says an error has occurred.

Comment: @Christofian: What happens when you click OK to dismiss the error? Does it work after that? Does the error come up again shortly after?

Comment: when I click OK, the pop up that is supposed to display the inbox messages is blank.

Comment: @Christofian: That's definitely a bug. I'll look into it.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison the bug appears to be fixed now :)

Comment: @GeorgeEdison I'm still getting that bug (blank popup).

Comment: There's an issue on Windows 7, Stack App window hides behind Taskbar, when it's on the right side of screen. [more here](https://github.com/nathan-osman/Stack-Alert/issues/9)

Comment: `Oops! We can’t find that page`. link is invalid :https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stack-alert/

Answer (score 11):

In my opinion, the icon is **too** large at `24 x 24`. Other Firefox toolbar icons are `16 x 16`. I used the following CSS in my `userChrome.css` file to make it the correct size:

```
.stackalert-button *
{
    width: 24px !important;
    height: 16px !important;
}
```

Comment: yeah. also, it is in topbar. why not to add an option to put on extension bar, on bottom of FF?

Comment: @kokbira, Luckily, it is open source, so you can update the plugin yourself :).

Answer (score 1):

[image: StackAlert not showing inbox]

You can see that StackAlert only pops a grey-bordered shadowed white box on my screen, not showing my inbox as it should. This does not happen only when I have 0 unread items, and sometimes it errors with a message.

Any solution/workaround is highly appreciated, 'cause I don't want to switch tabs to see anything else than the number of unread inbox notifications.

**Edit**: This is the error I'm talking about here.[image: SASAFF Error:]

If I click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button, close and reopen the box, the error disappears leading, again, to the white box pictured above. I don't know what causes this problem (possible add-ons: ABP, Ghostery).