# Stack Alert [Opera] - Keep tabs on your inbox without needing to have a Stack Exchange site open

Tags: app, extension

> ## Not using Opera?
>
> Don't worry, Stack Alert is available for other browsers as well. Visit the appropriate page for your browser below:
>
> - [Google Chrome](https://stackapps.com/q/2874)
> - [Mozilla Firefox](https://stackapps.com/q/2909)

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

What better way to keep an eye on your inbox than with an Opera extension? Now you can tell at a glance how many items are in your inbox without worrying about having a tab open to a Stack Exchange site.

#### License

[GPL version 3](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html)

#### Download

You can install the extension from the link below until I submit it to Opera:
http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/stackalert/stackalert.oex

#### Platform

Any platform that runs Opera (tested with Opera 11.60).

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

The extension is written in JavaScript.

You can get the code here: https://github.com/nathan-osman/Stack-Alert
*(look in the `opera/` folder for the Opera specific code)*

Comment: i have Opera.  No instructions on what to do after download.

Comment: You should be able to install it by clicking [this link](http://quickmediasolutions.com/stackalert/stackalert.oex).

Comment: Clicking on _Authorize Extension_ doesn't do anything. What should I do now?

Comment: @toscho: Temporarily turn off your popup blocker (and possibly restart Opera after turning it off). After clicking Authorize, a new tab should pop up showing Stack's external authorization page. You can turn it back on after authorizing the extension.

Comment: I had to click `Ctrl+Shift+Click` to get the popup in the background. Works now. :)

Comment: I'mm getting a 404 on Opera page. Where i can find this extension?

Comment: @Gremo: Sorry about that. I have updated the download link now.

Comment: Thanks for this opera extension, it should be placed on Opera site so it can be updated automatically.

Comment: link throws 404

Comment: Still throws a 404 for the Opera extension link, though thanks for providing it for pre Opera 15, some of us are "stuck".

Answer (score 2):

When trying to authorize extension Opera crashes.

Edit:
Opera 12.12 OS X Lion 10.7.5

Answer (score 1):

When I click on the [extension install link](http://quickmediasolutions.com/stackalert/stackalert.oex), I get a download prompt for a .ZIP file:
[image]

I have to rename this file to .OEX and open that file with Opera to have it install the extension.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Seems to be working fine now. Thanks for that. Also, please submit Stack Alert to the [Opera Add-ons site](https://addons.opera.com/en/).

Answer (score 1):

George, I have downloaded and installed successfully in Opera but can't authorize.

I can't get past :

> This app needs these permissions 
>   * Perpetual access to this data
>   * Read access to your global inbox
>   * To know what your accounts are on the Stack Exchange network
>
> You need to login to authorize this application.

What do I need to log into and where do I find these permissions?

Comment: You will need to log in to the Stack Exchange network - and the permissions will be granted when you allow the application to access your inbox data.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get past "Authorizing Application" screen.

Opera 11.6, Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

I get the same auth issue.

You need to login to authorize this application...

I have logged out and logged into Stack Exchange no difference? What is the resolution for this??

Comment: Resolved. Had to setup a Stack Exchange account, as opposed to the Stack Overflow account I use which then works