# ChatterBox - user script that adds inbox integration to Stack Exchange Chat!

Tags: script, api-v2, chat

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

I like Stack Exchange Chat, and with the feedbots it tends to be pretty easy to keep up with what's going on with the site. Except for one thing - my inbox.

So I wrote this UserScript that adds an "inbox" button with auto-refresh to the chat interface.

#### License

[BSD 2-clause license.](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php)

#### Download

To install, visit the [ChatterBox](http://agent86ix.github.io/stackapps/seci/) home page.

The script refreshes your inbox every minute, and shows new items at the top of the list.  The current maximum items that will be displayed is 10. Click the "inbox" button to toggle display of your inbox, and click "Inbox Cfg" to set relevant options (right now, just your access token).

You'll need an access token to use it, which you can get from the home page. Also, the link to get access tokens is in the "config" popup. Once you generate a token, push the "Inbox Cfg" button, put the code in the input field, and hit save. You can then close the configuration window by pressing "Inbox Cfg" or switch to the inbox view by pressing "Inbox." The number in the "Inbox" button is the number of unread items you have in your Stack Exchange Inbox.

#### Platform

This has been tested in the latest release versions of Chrome and Firefox. I'm not doing anything crazy that should be browser specific, so it ought to work in most sane UserScript implementations. Please feel free to report bugs.

### Contact

Me; You can usually find me on [Stack Apps Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27/stack-apps).

### Code

I stole some "injection" code from [SE Chat Modifications](https://stackapps.com/questions/2105/se-chat-modifications-keyboard-navigation-and-commands-for-chat), but otherwise I used this as a way to learn more about user scripts. Hopefully it isn't too terrible for my first time out. Suggestions are, of course, welcome.

Code is available in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/agent86ix/stackapps) (see the directory "seci").

---

If you're looking for something that's a bit more "browser-wide" than this, you might try:

[Stack Alert [Opera] - Keep tabs on your inbox without needing to have a Stack Exchange site open](https://stackapps.com/questions/2948/stack-alert-opera-keep-tabs-on-your-inbox-without-needing-to-have-a-stack-ex)

Comment: I think it should close when you click anywhere outside it, not just when you click on the button again.

Comment: @John Noted.  I'll work on that for the next release.

Comment: The Access Token request site seems down.

Comment: @Ullallulloo, thanks for reminding me.  I moved all the code and the pages around a while back.  You can reinstall the script, or click [this link](http://agent86ix.github.com/stackapps/seci/) to generate access tokens.

Comment: I've a question about the extension - http://stackapps.com/questions/3914/chatterbox-configuration-option-is-confusingly-worded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 3.1 is available today.  New improvements include:

- A configuration option that will allow you to mark unread items as read when you open your inbox.  (This is implemented by loading the inbox in the background and ignoring the result)
- The "inbox item body" is now shown alongside the title of the post.
- Some small CSS fixes.

Comment: Version 3.2 released, with John's request incorporated.  Clicking anywhere outside the dialog closes it now.

Answer (score 0):

I released a second version today, which has a much "fancier" style, similar to the [Stack Exchange SuperCollider Inbox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/66838#66838). Thanks goes to [Ronan Forman](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3098886#3098886) for suggesting this.

Comment: Version 2.1 released today, with a couple of fixes.  Some of the error messages were a bit unclear, and there were ways in which I would hide the the inbox/config tab buttons when they should have been shown.