# ChatterBox configuration option is confusingly worded

Tags: support

[ChatterBox - user script that adds inbox integration to Stack Exchange Chat!](https://stackapps.com/questions/2985/chatterbox-user-script-that-adds-inbox-integration-to-stack-exchange-chat)

I'm confused over the option:

> Mark items as unread when you view them:

Why would I want to mark items as **unread** when I view them? I can see marking items as **read** might be useful.

Does this option really mark items as read and is just misnamed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's misnamed.  The language there is confusing, and I'll change it in the Git version.

If you check this box, the extension will make a request for your inbox similar to the way the SuperCollider does when you click the little down arrow.  This will cause any unread items in your inbox to be marked as read.